# JAXB: Isn't it possible to use an XmlAdapter without @XmlJavaTypeAdapter?

Tags: java, jaxb, adapter

Can't I register a bunch of `XmlAdapter`s to `Marshaller`|`Unmarshaller` so that I wouldn't need to specify `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` on each filed, whose type isn't natively JAXB-supported?

I find it somewhat [redundant](http://icanhascheezburger.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/funny-pictures-cat-is-manager.jpg).

BTW, `someMarshaller.setAdapter(...)` seem not to do anything.

Answer (score 28):

This is a quite a good question !

The short answer is that **no**, using `setAdapter` on marshaller / unmarshaller does not mean that you don't have to use `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`.

Let me explain this with a hypothetical (yet valid!) scenario.

Consider in a web application, one fetches an event in the form of xml having following schema:

```
<xs:element name="event" >
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
           <!-- Avoiding other elements for concentrating on our adapter -->
            <xs:element name="performedBy" type="xs:string" />   
        </xs:sequence> 
    </xs:complexType>  
</xs:element>
```

Equivalent to this, your model will look like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="event")
@XmlType(name="")
public class Event {

     @XmlElement(required=true)
     protected String performedBy;
}
```

Now the application is already having a bean called `User` which maintains the detailed
information about the user.

```
public class User {

    private String id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    ..
}
```

Note that this `User` is not known to your JAXB Context.
For simplicity we have User as POJO, but it can be any Valid Java Class.

What application architect want is `Event`'s `performedBy` should be represented as `User`
to gain full details.

Here is where @XmlJavaTypeAdapter comes into picture

JAXBContext is aware about `performedBy` as `xs:string` , but it has to be represented as
`User` in memory in Java.

Modified model looks like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="event")
@XmlType(name="")
public class Event {

     @XmlElement(required=true)
     @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(UserAdapter.class) 
     protected User performedBy;
}
```

UserAdapter.java:

```
public class UserAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, User> {

     public String marshal(User boundType) throws   Exception {
             ..   
     } 

     public User unmarshal(String valueType) throws Exception {
             ..
     } 
}
```

The Adapter's definition says that -

1. BoundType is User (In Memeory representation)
2. ValueType is String (The data type JAXB Context is aware of)

**Coming to back to your question -**

> I find it somewhat redundant.
>
> BTW, someMarshaller.setAdapter(...) seem not to do anything.

Consider that our Adapter requires a class called UserContext in order to marshal / unmarshal sucessfully.

```
public class UserAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, User> {

     private UserContext userContext;

     public String marshal(User boundType) throws   Exception {
          return boundType.getId();
     } 

     public User unmarshal(String valueType) throws Exception {
          return userContext.findUserById(valueType);
     } 
}
```

Now the question is how will UserAdapter will fetch an instace of UserContext ??
As a good design one should always supply it while it has got instantiated ..

```
public class UserAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, User> {

     private UserContext userContext;

     public UserAdapter(UserContext userContext) {
        this.userContext = userContext;  
     } 

     public String marshal(User boundType) throws   Exception {
          return boundType.getId();
     } 

     public User unmarshal(String valueType) throws Exception {
          return userContext.findUserById(valueType);
     } 
}
```

But JAXB Runtime can only accept Adapter with No-args constructor ..
(Obviously JAXBContext does not know about application specific model)

So thankfully there is an option :D

You can tell your `unmarshaller` to use given instance of `UserAdapter` rather than instating it by own its own.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String... args) { 
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.getInstance(Event.class);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();

      UserContext userContext = null; // fetch it from some where
      unmarshaller.setAdapter(UserAdapter.class, new UserAdapter(userContext));

      Event event = (Event) unmarshaller.unmarshal(..);
   }
}
```

`setAdapter` method is available on both `Marshaller` & `Unmarshaller`

Note:

1. `setAdapter` on marshaller / unmarshaller does not mean that you don't have to use `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`.

   ```
   @XmlRootElement(name="event")
   @XmlType(name="")
   public class Event {

       @XmlElement(required=true)
       // @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(UserAdapter.class) 
       protected User performedBy;
   }
   ```

   If you omit this JAXB runtime has no clue that User is your Bound Type & Value Type is something else. It will try to marshal `User` as is & u will end up having wrong xml 
   (or validation failure if enabled)
2. While we have taken a scenario where Adapter is required to be with arguments, hence
   use `setAdapter` method.

   Some adavanced usages are also there, where in even if you have default no-arg constructor, yet you provide an instance of the Adapter

   May this adapter is configured with data, which marshal / unmarshal operation is using !

Comment: **So Short answer is NO.** You can not use XmlAdapter without using @xmlJavaTypeAdapter annotation

Answer (score 9):

You can use the package-info.java

That's called "package level".

Example :
put a package-info.java in the same package that the class you want to marshall/unmarshall.

Suppose you have a class mypackage.model.A and an adapter CalendarAdapter in mypackage.adapter.
Declare a package-info.java file in mypackage.model containing :

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = CalendarAdapter.class, type = Calendar.class)
})
package mypackage.model;

import java.util.Calendar;
import mypackage.adapter.CalendarAdapter;
```

All field of type Calendar in the class A will be marshalled or unmarshalled with the CalendarAdapter.

You can find useful informations there :
http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxb-and-package-level-xmladapters.html