# JAX-B set top down unmarhalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm trying to optimize my code during the unmarhal of an XML source.
I have this xml:

```
<Parent name="X">
    <List>
        <Element name="A">
        <Element name="B">
        <Element name="C">
    </List>
</Parent>
<Parent name="Y">
    <List>
        <Element name="A">
        <Element name="B">
        <Element name="C">
    </List>
</Parent>
```

I want to use the Parent's name value into the Element because if the parent 's name is X the elements name will be X+element.getName(), otherwise it will be Y+element.getName().
What I'm trying to do is to set the correct value during the unmarshal process, in the setName(String name) method of the Element bean. This becaus I don't want to cycle over Parents and Elements after the unmarshalling.
The problem is that the JAX-B unmarshal approach is bottom up: it creates the object Element before creating object Parent so I don't know how to get the parent attribute name.
Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342888/jaxb-xjc-parent-child-parent-navigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [create a method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshalEventCallback) void `afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller, Object parent)` that will be called after unmarshalling. In this method you could change the `name` property of your object as required.

You might also want to annotate your `elements` property with `@XmlElementWrapper(name="List")` to make `Element` objects direct children of `Parent` object.

ps. This answer is almost 1:1 with the answer in the following question:

> [JAXB / XJC parent-child-parent navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342888/jaxb-xjc-parent-child-parent-navigation)

Comment: Thanks, it seems what I need to. I have a doubt about XmlElementWrapper: I'm not sure to have understood where I need to put the annotation