# (moxy) jaxb marshaling and hibernate proxy objects

Tags: hibernate, proxy, jaxb, lazy-loading, moxy

In the last couple of days I have tried to make support for XML marshalling/unmarshalling of a Hibernate model, using MOXy JAXB. Trying to do this, I have run into a problem with hibernates proxy objects.
Consider something like:

```
public class User {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address")
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
}

public abstract class Address {
    // Something
}

public class CoolAddress extends Address {
    public String getSomething() {
        return something;
    }
}
```

I have tried to map this code using MOXy JAXB in the following way:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class User {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address")
    @XmlElement
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlSeeAlso(CoolAddress.class)
public abstract class Address {
    // Something
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class CoolAddress extends Address {
    @XmlElement
    public String getSomething() {
        return something;
    }
}
```

My problem is that hibernate instantiates a proxy object of the address obtained by calling getAddress() on a User. Then, when JAXB tries to marshal the object, it can't find out that it  actually is a CoolAddress it is trying to marshal, which results in that properties in CoolAddress not being marshaled.

I have googled/considered the following possible solutions:

- In some way get a callback from JAXB, allowing me to replace the object being marshaled with another. This would allow me to obtain the real object from the proxy.
- Touch all objects in the model which will make hibernate fetch the real objects. I have not been able to find any smart way doing this other than manually running through all non-transient properties, which is quiet tedious.
- Set hibernate to use eager fetching in the session I am marshaling the models.

I'm looking for alternative suggestions, or if one of the above suggestions is possible (and easy) to implement. Any help is appreciated :).

Comment: Does `CoolAddress` extend `Address`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've forgot to write that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To solve this Hibernate issue you may be able to use an `XmlAdapter`.  The XmlAdapter would look something like where the logic in the marshal method is to convert from the proxy to the real object:

```
package forum6838323;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class AddressAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Address, Address> {

    @Override
    public Address unmarshal(Address v) throws Exception {
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public Address marshal(Address v) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

You configure the `XmlAdapter` as follows:

```
public class User {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AddressAdapter.class)
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
}
```

If you need to pass an initialized XmlAdapter to the JAXB marshaller, you can do that as well, see the following for an example:

- [Using JAXB to cross reference XmlIDs from two XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319024/using-jaxb-to-cross-reference-xmlids-from-two-xml-files/5327425#5327425)

---

**Alternative Using EclipseLink JPA**

Note:  The lazy loading in EclipseLink JPA does not cause this issue:

**User**

```
package forum6838323;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@XmlRootElement
public class User  {

    private int id;
    Address address;

    @Id
    @XmlAttribute
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address")
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

**Address**

```
package forum6838323;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorValue("ADDRESS")
@XmlSeeAlso(CoolAddress.class)
public class Address {

    private int id;
    private String street;

    @Id
    @XmlAttribute
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

}
```

**CoolAddress**

```
package forum6838323;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("COOL")
public class CoolAddress extends Address {

    private String something;

    public String getSomething() {
        return something;
    }

    public void setSomething(String something) {
        this.something = something;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum6838323;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Forum6838323");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        User user = em.find(User.class, 2);
        System.out.println("user.address BEFORE marshal:  " + user.address);

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(User.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(user, System.out);

        System.out.println("user.address AFTER marshal:  " + user.address);
    }

}
```

**Output**

You can see from the output that the address value is being lazily loaded since the field is null before the marshal and populated afterwards:

```
user.address BEFORE marshal:  null
[EL Finest]: 2011-07-27 11:47:13.118--ServerSession(23503403)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Execute query ReadObjectQuery(name="Forum6838323" referenceClass=Address )
[EL Finest]: 2011-07-27 11:47:13.118--ServerSession(23503403)--Connection(10272075)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection acquired from connection pool [default].
[EL Fine]: 2011-07-27 11:47:13.118--ServerSession(23503403)--Connection(10272075)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--SELECT ID, TYPE, STREET, SOMETHING FROM ADDRESS WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [2]
[EL Finest]: 2011-07-27 11:47:13.118--ServerSession(23503403)--Connection(10272075)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Connection released to connection pool [default].
[EL Finest]: 2011-07-27 11:47:13.118--UnitOfWork(6131844)--Thread(Thread[main,5,main])--Register the existing object forum6838323.CoolAddress@109ea96
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<user id="2">
    <address xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="coolAddress" id="2">
        <street>2 B Road</street>
        <something>Cool Road</something>
    </address>
</user>
user.address AFTER marshal:  forum6838323.CoolAddress@83b1b
```

Comment: Than you for a very nice answer.