# Read Excel spreadsheet xml file[Java]

Tags: java, xml, excel, parsing

I have Excel spreadsheet xml file(generated from excel via save as Excel XML Spreadsheet 2003) and I need to extract data from it in java.

I found similar topic:
[How to load old Microsoft Office XML file (Excel) using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089039/how-to-load-old-microsoft-office-xml-file-excel-using-java)

But last answer was 2 years ago - something could change.

If you have any idea how to parse excel xml file(or convert it) please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem some time ago, ended up writing a SAX parser to read the XML file. I wrote a blog post about it [here](http://blog.jbaysolutions.com/2015/03/04/parsing-excel-spreadsheet-xml/).

You can find the sample project to parse the file in [Github](https://github.com/jbaysolutions/excel-xml-reader).

Answer (score 0):

You can for sure export your Excel file into pure XML. 
Then it will be various libs for that:

- [JDOM](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-jdom-example/)
- [SAX](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/)
- [DOM](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)
- [Simple XML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/)
- and more...

You should also read this topic: [Best way to read XML in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188101/best-way-to-read-xml-in-java)
Enjoy

**EDIT**

 If you need to extract data from Excel XML then your file has extention XLS, right?
The you can use easly - [jXLS](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I know I can export excel file into pure XML but I have already generated files as Excel XML Spreadsheet 2003(It was not done by me, but I must proceed with this files).

Comment: Then try jXLS library -> link in answer above

Comment: I tied jXLS: 

List testKist = new ArrayList();
testKist.add("test");
Map beans = new HashMap(); 
beans.put("departments", testKist);

XLSTransformer transformer = new XLSTransformer();
transformer.transformXLS(filePath, beans, "C:" + File.separator + "text.xls");

but I get:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Your InputStream was neither an OLE2 stream, nor an OOXML stream

as source file I put my excel xml file.