# java xml serialization+reference to external object

Tags: java, serialization, jaxb, xml-serialization, xstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using JAXB to cross reference XmlIDs from two XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319024/using-jaxb-to-cross-reference-xmlids-from-two-xml-files)

Let's consider following classes  (it's not a real code, it just shows my problem):

```
class Currency {
    private String fullName;
    private String symbol;
    private String isoCode;
    ...
}

class Region {
    ...
    private List<Currency> acceptedCurrencies;
    ...
}
```

Now I would like to store all currencies and regions in separate XML files, rather than in one big file, so I would like to have something like "reference to external object".

How I imagine such xml-s:

```
 <currency>
      <fullName>euro</fullName>
      <symbol>€</symbol>
      <isoCode>EUR</isoCode>
 </currency>

 <region>
      <currencies>
           <currency>euro</currency> <!--  Currency.name is threaten as ID -->
      </currencies>
 </region>
```

Is it somehow possible (besides implementing own framework for this)?